# Increase pdflatex limits

Tags: pdf, pdftex

A pdf is generated from doxygen generated tex files. One function prototype is extremely long, generating a line in the corresponding tex file that is 1122 characters long.

When pdflatex is run, no pdf is generated - no error is given

Strangely, the length is not what causes the error. Before every capital letter, the escape sequence + is placed. is appears that there are too many escape sequences on that line: if I remove one of them (and add the same amount or more normal characters), the pdf is generated.

**How can I increase the capabilities of pdflatex, so it can cope with more escape sequences?**

I'm running this on Windows7 from a command shell, using the binaries from MikTex.

---

The line that fails the pdf generation is:

```
void \hyperlink{a00001_a08fada22bcd057759e344830bbaac50e}{xx\+aa\+bb\+cc\+\_\+\+dd} (int ee\+ff\+gg, \hyperlink{a00001_a6f71136ece8b9a87173c5c86bc6f248f}{aa\+bb\+cc\+\_\+\+ee\+bb\+ff\+\_\+t} eebb\+ffed, \hyperlink{a00001_a33a2104b20eef6806443b52c2b064159}{aa\+bb\+cc\+\_\+\+ee\+bb\+hh\+\_\+t} r, \hyperlink{a00001_af69c4d93122a8eb40c12d6ceae7d682e}{aa\+bb\+cc\+\_\+\+ee\+bb\+ii\+\_\+t} s, \hyperlink{a00001_aab88436ec45f3c97141d5e4ed40dec81}{aa\+bb\+cc\+\_\+\+ee\+bb\+jj\+\_\+t} t, \hyperlink{a00001_a863a5fdf396307748fcdc46b1f5e2fb9}{aa\+bb\+cc\+\_\+\+ee\+bb\+kk\+\_\+t} u, \hyperlink{a00001_a0209334ce20c0d6bd53a72771867a098}{aa\+bb\+cc\+\_\+\+ee\+bb\+ll\+\_\+t} v, \hyperlink{a00001_ab028b29cfe99d78f2d1f6fa163e24eee}{aa\+bb\+cc\+\_\+\+ee\+mm\+nn\+\_\+t} w, \hyperlink{a00001_ae4306c7f1ad814eb2f719542628238f9}{aa\+bb\+cc\+\_\+\+ee\+mm\+oo\+\_\+t} x, \hyperlink{a00001_a4febae17a1d3e78d23df7995a0caf4f5}{aa\+bb\+cc\+\_\+\+ee\+pp\+qq\+\_\+t} y, \hyperlink{a00001_aee53a9af1c43bb5e2b3096c2355a9ec8}{aa\+bb\+cc\+\_\+\+ee\+rr\+ss\+tt\+\_\+t} z)
```

---

The modified line with which pdf generation succeeds - one `\+` is replaced with `xx`:

```
void \hyperlink{a00001_a08fada22bcd057759e344830bbaac50e}{xxxxaa\+bb\+cc\+\_\+\+dd} (int ee\+ff\+gg, \hyperlink{a00001_a6f71136ece8b9a87173c5c86bc6f248f}{aa\+bb\+cc\+\_\+\+ee\+bb\+ff\+\_\+t} eebb\+ffed, \hyperlink{a00001_a33a2104b20eef6806443b52c2b064159}{aa\+bb\+cc\+\_\+\+ee\+bb\+hh\+\_\+t} r, \hyperlink{a00001_af69c4d93122a8eb40c12d6ceae7d682e}{aa\+bb\+cc\+\_\+\+ee\+bb\+ii\+\_\+t} s, \hyperlink{a00001_aab88436ec45f3c97141d5e4ed40dec81}{aa\+bb\+cc\+\_\+\+ee\+bb\+jj\+\_\+t} t, \hyperlink{a00001_a863a5fdf396307748fcdc46b1f5e2fb9}{aa\+bb\+cc\+\_\+\+ee\+bb\+kk\+\_\+t} u, \hyperlink{a00001_a0209334ce20c0d6bd53a72771867a098}{aa\+bb\+cc\+\_\+\+ee\+bb\+ll\+\_\+t} v, \hyperlink{a00001_ab028b29cfe99d78f2d1f6fa163e24eee}{aa\+bb\+cc\+\_\+\+ee\+mm\+nn\+\_\+t} w, \hyperlink{a00001_ae4306c7f1ad814eb2f719542628238f9}{aa\+bb\+cc\+\_\+\+ee\+mm\+oo\+\_\+t} x, \hyperlink{a00001_a4febae17a1d3e78d23df7995a0caf4f5}{aa\+bb\+cc\+\_\+\+ee\+pp\+qq\+\_\+t} y, \hyperlink{a00001_aee53a9af1c43bb5e2b3096c2355a9ec8}{aa\+bb\+cc\+\_\+\+ee\+rr\+ss\+tt\+\_\+t} z)
```

Comment: It's impossible to fully run your code unless you give the `\hypertarget{}` that are referenced. Although preliminarily I seem to be able to reproduce the same problem with Texlive under Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently `\+` may have something to do with tabbing, but only within a tabbing environment (within a `\begin{tabbing}` and `\end{tabbing}` block). See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Command_Glossary and http://noodle.med.yale.edu/latex/latex2e-html/ltx-58.html

When defining `\newcommand{\+}{}` somewhere before the jungle of `\+`'s start, the command will be expanded to void, and the generation succeeds. In doxygen this can be done e.g. in a `header.tex` which can be given along to doxygen using `LATEX_HEADER` in the doxyfile configuration file.